# Output array data from GET

Tags: html, arrays, post

I'd like to know if there's a way that one can output data from a form sent by a page. The data is sent in array form, and the form looks like this:

```
<form method="post" action="/?module=scoreboard&n=index">
  <table width="101" border="0" align="center">
  <tr>
    <th colspan="2" scope="col"><p>Select Division(s)</p>
      <p>&nbsp;</p></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td width="74"> <label for="div1">Division 1</label></td>
   <td width="20"><input type="checkbox" name="div[]" id="div1" value="1" />
  </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td><label for="div2">Division 2</label></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="div[]" id="div2" value="2"/>
</td>
</tr>
 <tr>
<td><label for="div3">Division 3</label></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="div[]" id="div3" value="3" />
</td>
</tr>
 <tr>
<td><label for="div4">Division 4</label></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="div[]" id="div4" value="4" />
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2"><p>&nbsp;
  </p>
  <p>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Display Standings" />
  </p></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

I need to output the data from this form, in hidden fields so the page can be refreshed at certain periods of time.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you're using an array HTML-side, you simply need to use the corresponding PHP array in your POST data.

For example, to see if the 1st `div[]` checkbox was checked, you'd need to see if the corresponding value is in the $_POST['div'] array. For example:

```
if(in_array(1, $_POST['div']) {
    // The first checkbox was selected. Do exciting things here.
}
```

To check the second, use `in_array(2, $_POST['div'])` and so on.

Comment: It'll take a lot, so I could use, in array?

Comment: @Shamil I'm not sure what you mean, although you *might* be referring about an earlier revision of my answer. (I updated it to use in_array a few minutes ago, as I thought it was more obvious what was going on.)

Comment: @Shamil Cool. Hope it goes well. :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
print_r($_POST);
```

to see the complete structure of the sent data.

Comment: Here's what it comes out as: ` Array
(
   [div] => Array
       (
           [0] => 1
           [1] => 2
           [2] => 3
           [3] => 4
       )

   [submit] => Display Standings
)
` How do I use that?

Comment: Ok, this means that all the four checkboxes are checked. You could do a foreach($_POST['div'] as $checked) to output the hidden fields.

Comment: @Shamil it's your data you tell me.

Comment: I'm already doing that to output data from the database, but how would I reconstruct a form from it?

Comment: Hi, what do you mean by "database"?
You can output it by
foreach($_POST['div'] as $checked) echo '<input type="hidden" name="' . $checked . '" value="1" />';
I don't really get your idea... why do you have to store the data again in hidden fields? Why no Session stuff?